# Java Decimal issue with format #.# in android

Tags: java, android, decimal

I have used this following code to get the decimal format and set it to edit text.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
editSoilDepth.setText(decimalFormat.format(5.58f));
```

If I do so it will give me out put as: **5.9**
but i do not want to replace the decimal first value and want to print as **5.5**

How can i do so?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`

Comment: but what if there is decimal "5.889"...at that time i want "5.8" output.

Comment: Try this NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.format(yourNumber);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line before using the `DecimalFormat`:

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

        decimalFormat.format(5.58f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 10.0) / 10.0;
```